Is it possible to import an image into the UV unwrapping of an object?
Im making a 3d model of an animal crossing character for a friend. I know most artists draw directly on their model in order to get patterns on it, but I don't have a drawing tablet and im not the best at drawing with a mouse. I do however have a regular tablet, and I use that for my drawing most of the time.
I was wondering if I could import a drawing with no background into an unwrapped version of my model?
Sorry if this doesn't make much sense, I'm still learning blender so some of the vocab is difficult for me to use

Hello, you need to unwrap your object, with the Smart UV Project for example, give it a material with an Image Texture plugged into the Base Color of the Principled BSDF, and paint on the surface of your object in the 3D view

Yes, you unwrap your object in Edit Mode while using the UV Editor so you can place your UVs onto the area of the image texture you want to use. It means a lot of work depending on how intricate your model is.

@moonboots what's smart uv project? Is it an addon? I'm extremely new to uv unwrapping.

Select the whole mesh in Edit mode and press U > Smart UV Project, it's just an unwrap option
